# Microsoft Graph API Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed. when using /search/query

Tags: api, outlook, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to search calendars by name with the [`v1.0/search/query` endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/search-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) from the Graph API. However even I'm trying the examples from the [Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/graph/graph-explorer) I get the following error:

```json
{
    "error": {
        "code": "InternalServerError",
        "message": "Invalid URI: The hostname could not be parsed.",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2022-03-28T19:50:56",
            "request-id": "ddb02afc-1c82-4884-d352-4a8d80809b20",
            "client-request-id": "58147981-de34-ba11-ab1f-6e17dca603f9"
        }
    }
}
```

[Graph Explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-US/graph/graph-explorer):
[image]

Is this endpoint still supported? Is it not allowed for Applications?

Answer (score 0):

From the output we can see that , in the tip its saying for adding the permissions for accessing Calendar events and its API's.
[image]

so please try to add those permissions and retry again. Please refer this [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#calendars-permissions)

Comment: Do you know where to grant these permissions? Under the permissions tab it's empty.

Comment: You can assign these permissions for the app on the azure Ad portal itself and for more info on permissions please refer this [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/permissions-reference#calendars-permissions)